# Preseed Ubuntu Server from USB (preseed not found)

Tags: usb, preseed, kickstart

I'm trying to make a USB installer for Ubuntu Server 14.04, but I'm having some trouble with the preseed file when booting from USB.

I have a kickstart file and a preseed. The kickstart file works, but the preseed doesn't. This is only an issue, when booting from USB, but not with CD.

I change isolinux/txt.cfg dependent on the install metode. For CD the file looks like this:

```
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/sda/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed quiet --
```

For USB:

```
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append file=/media/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=hd:sda:/ks.cfg preseed/file=hd:sda:/ks.preseed quiet --
```

I know it looks weird with the kickstart-file located in cdrom:/sda/ks.cfg, but I couldn't get the USB to search in the root for the kickstart when typing hd:sda:/ks.cfg, so I made a quick fix and just created a folder called "sda". Although, this doesn't help with the preseed file.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was due to 7zip/Windows file paths. If the file path and name exceeds some limit, the names are truncated, which prevented certain files from being found during installation.

The fix was to use Rufus USB creator instead of the creator from http://pendrivelinux.com